# How to trigger local reference in parent component from child component event in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, components, angular-material2

I am trying to work out how to trigger a local reference in a parent component template i.e. `#rightNav` from a child component template click event `(click)="rightNav.open()"` using [Material 2 sidenav](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/demo-app/sidenav). I think I need to use the `@ViewChild` annotation, but not sure how.

**Child component template (app-conditions-list):**

```
<div *ngFor="let condition of conditions" [class.selected]="condition === selectedCondition"
            (click)="rightNav.open()"></div>
```

**Parent component template (condition component):**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { ConditionsListComponent } from './listComponent/conditions-list.component';


@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-conditions',
    template: `
            <md-sidenav #rightNav align="end" mode="side">
            "Condition details will open here on click event"
            </md-sidenav>
            <app-conditions-list></app-conditions-list>`,
    styleUrls: ['./conditions.component.css'],
    directives: [
        ConditionsListComponent,
    ]
})

export class ConditionsComponent  {
    title = "Conditions Manager"
}
```

The child component is nested in the parent component template.
Thanks!

Comment: For me it's not clear how `<md-list-item>` and `<md-sidenav>` are related. What do you mean by "parent component"?

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer. I cleaned up the code to remove irrelevant code. The parent component is where the #rightNav reference is.

Comment: Please add more code. To me it's still entirely unclear what you try to accomplish.

Comment: What's the selector of the `condition-list` component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an output to the child component and listen to events from it

```
export class ConditionsListComponent {
  @Output() navOpen:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
}
```

You can use a template variable to refer to sibling elements like:

```
<div #rightNav align="end" mode="side" (close)="close($event)"</div>
<app-conditions-list (navOpen)="rightNav.open()"></app-conditions-list>`,
```

and event an event like

```
<div *ngFor="let condition of conditions" [class.selected]="condition === selectedCondition"
        (click)="navOpen.next(null)"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to bubble your event up from your child to your parent :

```
The child :  

export class ConditionsListComponent  {
   @Output('myEvent') myEvent = new EventEmitter();

   private bubbleUp($event:Event){

     myEvent.emit($event)
  }
}
```

It's view :

```
  <div *ngFor="let condition of conditions" [class.selected]="condition === selectedCondition"
        (click)="bubbleUp($event)"></div>
```

And the parent :

```
     import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'app-conditions',
template: `
        <div #rightNav align="end" mode="side" (close)="close($event)"</div>
        <app-conditions-list (myEvent)='gotTheEvent($event)' ></app-conditions-list>`,
styleUrls: ['./conditions.component.css'],
providers: [],
directives: [
    ConditionsListComponent,
]
})

export class ConditionsComponent  {
   title = "Conditions Manager";

   gotTheEvent($event){

     console.log('I got this event from my child',$event);

    //you can do whatever you want : 

     rightNav.open()
  }
}
```